# Why relay in graphene-django?

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

I would like to know why Relay spec is in graphene-django? I understand that using relay in graphene-django we get pagination and filters by default.

My requirement is to call graphql apis from React (for Web) and use Apollo client for Android and iOS.

1. Will there be a problem for clients to consume graphql apis written using graphene-django with Relay compliant especially pagination (and cursors) feature?
2. How to support subscriptions using graphene-django?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @RajKrishan Your question is in fact two independent questions, and they must be divided. First question is not specific to graphene-python at all.

Answer (score 1):

1. There isn't any problem with consuming Relay-compliant graphene-django API. My team at work is currently using [react-query library](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query), and it works fabulously!
2. As mentioned in this graphene-django [Github issue](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/120), GraphQL subscription is currently not supported out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Relay is the client-side middleware between React and any GraphQL server. Relay Specs provided by graphene-django just make it easier to use relay with graphene-django. They are not strictly necessary

1. There should not be a problem for clients to consume graphql apis written using graphene-django
2. Subscriptions are handled by a separate package - [graphene-django-subscriptions](https://pypi.org/project/graphene-django-subscriptions/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just few more clarifications. "They are not strictly necessary" - How to implement pagination without using relay in graphene-django?. Also "There should not be a problem for clients to consume graphql apis written using graphene-django" - With Relay implemented in graphene-django?.

Comment: Relay Specs are not necessary to use graphene-django as a GraphQL Server. They are there only to make using Relay easier/quicker. Pagination of results is provided by graphene-django. Relay is not implemented *in* graphene-django. Relay runs on the client (in the browser), and provides a bridge between React and any GraphQL server (which graphene-django provides). Pagination of data is provided by graphene-django. UI Pagination is provided by you, in React. Again, Relay is just the bridge between the two.

Comment: But Relay exists as a module in **graphene** package and adds quite a few functionality, pagination and filters as example. Also, some disadvantages - the shadowing of "id" field in models, as example. The question "_can_ we quickly implement pagination without using relay?" is a open question till this time.

Comment: @Psion As far as I know, only `graphene_django_extras` package provides simple and Relay Server Spec independent realization. But I highly discourage you to use this package - it has a lot of places with strange behavior and places where is hard to tune default logic. Probably, just using Relay support will be the best solution.